# vuejs pass data to template html attributes

Tags: vue.js

I'm very new to Vuejs. 
I see how to pass data (variables) into components, but in my code I need to get thoses variables in the HTML attributes of the template.

Here my HTML :

```
<div id="activities" class="row text-center activities">
     <myimage text="{{ art_text }}" type="art"></myimage>
</div>
```

Here my Vuejs code (delimiters changed, because of Twig) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/vue.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    Vue.component('myimage', {
        delimiters: ['${', '}'],
        props: ['text', 'type'],
        template: '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3" style="padding-top: 20px;"><h3><a title="${text}" href="#"><span> <img style="width:220px;" alt="Image ${type}"> </span></a></h3><span>${text}</span></div>'
    });

    new Vue({
        el: '#activities'
    });
</script>
```

But for example, in my template I don't see why "title" attribute don't get the variable ${text} ...

Is there another way to pass data from custom element to HTML attributes of the template ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is:

> Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use `v-bind` or the colon shorthand instead.

Also, [per docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes):

> Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes. Instead, use a `v-bind` directive.

So, instead of `title="${text}"` (which is, because you are using  custom `delimiters`, the equivalent of `title="{{ text }}"`),

**Use:**

```
v-bind:title="text"
```

**Or** `v-bind`'s [shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand)**:**

```
:title="text"
```